# Analytic forms of $\frac{\sinh(2\pi/7)}{\sinh^{2}(3\pi/7)} - \frac{\sinh(\pi/7)}{\sinh^{2}(2\pi/7)} + \frac{\sinh(3\pi/7)}{\sinh^{2}(\pi/7)}$

Tags: number-theory, hyperbolic-functions, transcendental-numbers

On page 183 of Berndt's *Ramanujan's Notebooks* Vol. 4, eq. 32.34 reads:

$$
\frac{\sin(2\pi/7)} {\sin^{2}(3\pi/7)} - \frac{\sin(\pi/7)}{\sin^{2}(2\pi/7)} + \frac{\sin(3\pi/7)} {\sin^{2}(\pi/7)} = 2\sqrt{7}
$$

If the sines are replaced by hyperbolic sines

$$
\frac{\sinh(2\pi/7)} {\sinh^{2}(3\pi/7)} - \frac{\sinh(\pi/7)} {\sinh^{2}(2\pi/7)} + \frac{\sinh(3\pi/7)} {\sinh^{2}(\pi/7)} \approx  8.196723051395340184\ldots ?
$$

Wolfram alpha believes this is a transcendental number.

Is there another analytic expression for it besides the stated one?

Comment: In the quoted result, the numerator of the middle subtracted term should be $\sin(\pi/7)$ rather than the (confusing) $\sin(2\pi/7)$, which would cancel with one power of the middle term denominator. This is backed up by maple's calculation with the adjusted middle term, which numerically (when squared) gives $28$. Likely you want to adjust the numerator of the other expression in the same way.

Comment: @coffeemath: oops! fixed.

Comment: Given  $e^\pi$ transcendental, so that $e^{\pi/7}$ is also, does it follow that integer powers of it are algebraically independent? If so it doesn't seem surprising the expression gives a transcendental number. [I'm a bit vague here on the details.]